# How can I force Selenium to run tests only after $(document).ready() has completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, automated-tests

Our site does a lot of JavaScript/jQuery work in the $(document).ready() function, setting up buttons, loading content via ajax, etc.  Selenium waits until the DOM is loaded, but then proceeds to test before .ready() has completed.

A partial solution seems to be using a check to see if the browser has pending ajax requests:

```
selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().jQuery.active == 0
```

However that doesn't ensure that we aren't still setting up bindings for buttons and things.

Any help will be **greatly** appreciated.  The current 'best' suggestion is adding an element to the page at the end of the .ready() method, which Selenium can catch as a signal to start working, but the idea of adding code like this for testing purposes seems sketchy at best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use the window load check. Try this:

```
$(window).load(function(){  
  selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().jQuery.active == 0 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> The current 'best' suggestion is
>   adding an element to the page at the
>   end of the .ready() method, which
>   Selenium can catch as a signal to
>   start working, but the idea of adding
>   code like this for testing purposes
>   seems sketchy at best.

I don't personally think that modifying your code to improve testability is a bad thing. If you really would rather not pollute your production pages then use some templating tool like PHP to output the code only in development/debug mode.

Also, you don't need to use the DOM for this. Selenium has access to the the full javascript context in the page so you can just use a global variable as a flag. Maybe something that is unlikely to be used by others like `SELENIUM_PAGE_FULLY_READY` then have Selenium check for its existence.